# What are the usages of the doubting clauses here?

Tags: grammar-identification, subordinate-clause

On P327 in Section 116. Doubting Clauses of Keller's Learn to Read Latin:

> When an indirect question introduced by num, an (whether), or another interrogative word is preceded by a verb or other expression of doubting, the indirect question is sometimes called a dubting clause. For example:

> ```
> Omnes dubitabant num Cicero locuturus essset. (dubito [1-tr] doubt)
> ```

> ```
> All men were doubting whether Cicero was going to speak.
> ```

> ```
> Dubium est an nostri vincant. (dubium/dubii. n. doubt)
> ```

> ```
> There is a doubt whether our men are conquering.
> ```

> When the expression of doubting is negated, or when negation is implied, the doubting clause is introduced by the conjunction quin (that). For example:

> ```
> Non dubitavi quin Cicero locuturus esset.
> ```

> ```
> I did not doubt that Cicero was going to speak.
> ```

> ```
> Nullum dubium est quin nostri vincant.
> ```

> ```
> There is no doubt that our men are conquering.
> ```

Is it correct that in the first and third examples, the doubting clauses are noun clauses functioning as direct object of verb dubito?

In the second and fourth examples, what is the usage of the doubting clauses for noun dubium? Are they noun clauses or adjective clauses?

Thanks.

Comment: Why do you think the distinction matters?